# Contractor scheduling tool

Tags: scheduling

I am looking for a software tool that could help me manage the scheduling of contractor workers for a big organization.  The organization may have sub branches that may or may not want to hire that contractor.

The idea would be that the contractor can set his availabilties, then each branch on which he is registered can offer him a contract. The other way around may be possible, the organisation requesting a contractor may open a time slot then the contractors can apply.

If a contractor is hired by a branch, other branches sees him as unavailable. If he cancel, the next one that applied can be notified.

I'd like some feature so that the system is easy to use. Automated sms alert, an phone app maybe. Anything that makes the tool accessible an worthy of maintaining.

Anybody knows something that could match these criterias? Seems like a common use case to me.

The tool can be commercial or open source. Maintaining servers is an option.

Thanks